# active_admin and adding multiple images to gallery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, activeadmin

I'm using active_admin and carrierwave gems. Have two simple models:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gallery_id, :file
  belongs_to :gallery

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :description, :title, :file, :images_attributes
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

Now my active_admin form for Gallery looks like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Gallery" do
    f.input :title
  end
  f.has_many :images do |ff|
    ff.input :file
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Now I can upload one file, click "Add New Image" and upload another one. Instead of it, I'd like to click "Add new Image", select multiple files and upload them all at once. Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: have you try update plugin `carrierwave` use javascrips such as jQuery?

Comment: +1 on this question. Have you figured this out yet?

Answer (score 1):

For a Gallery form with multiple image uploads you can try this

**admin/galleries.rb**

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Gallery" do 
      f.input :name
    end
    f.has_many :images do |ff|
      ff.input :file
    end
  end
```

**In model/gallery.rb:**

```
attr_accessible :images_attributes
```

**In model/gallery.rb (add after relations):**

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
```