# How to implement multiple selection with ActiveAdmin on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, carrierwave

I have two models called Project and ProjectImage, and each project has multiple project-images. I want to have a form with ActiveAdmin that lets you select and upload multiple images at once.

This is NOT what I want (and what I have) :

```rb
# app/admin/project.rb

form do |f|
  f.inputs "Project" do
    # Other columns come here
    f.has_many :project_images do |ff|
      ff.input :image
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

This requires you to click Add button for each single file, which is very annoying when you want to upload twenty images.

Does anyone have ideas?

I'm using:

- Ruby (2.1.5)
- Rails (4.1.8)
- ActiveAdmin (1.0.0.pre1)
- Carrierwave (0.10.0)

Note: there is a similar question here ([active_admin and adding multiple images to gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625437/active-admin-and-adding-multiple-images-to-gallery)), which doesn't have any actual answers. (The code in the answer does exactly same as what the questioner did.)